# Proper grounding with a generator interlock kit in my sub-panel

Tags: circuit-breaker, generator, transfer-switch

My main panel/meter can is outside, but I want to install the interlock kit on the sub-panel inside my house to make it easier to adjust the loading. That part is easy, but my concern is how to properly ground it. Should I attach the ground to the ground bus in my sub-panel or should I still run a separate ground wire to my bonded main panel?

Comment: Your sub panel should already be grounded to the main panel, unless quite old.  If not with a ground wire, then by metal conduit.

Comment: Is the feeder from the main panel to the subpanel a 3-wire or a 4-wire feeder?